# Upload image to server with react-native-image-picker got error

Tags: react-native, axios, form-data, react-native-image-picker

Today I try to upload an image from my phone to server using `react-native-image-picker` but I got problem with it. Here my code:

```
   ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {

            if (response.didCancel) {
                console.log('User cancelled image picker');
            } else if (response.error) {
                console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
            } else if (response.customButton) {
                console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
            } else {
                var FormData = require('form-data');
                const data = new FormData();
                data.append('file', {
                    uri: `file://${response.path}`,
                    type: response.type,
                    name: response.fileName

                });
               


                Axios.post('https://api.hoc68.com/api/v1/upload_files', data, {
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${stateTree.user.token_key}`,
                        'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    }
                }).then(res => console.log(res.data)).catch(e => console.log(e.response.data))

                console.log(response.path + ' ' + response.type);
            }
        });
```

When I ran code I got this error  `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.response.data')`. Anyone can help me fix this error ?

Comment: what is inside your res.data?

Comment: It didn't log res.data , it only catch error and when I logged it to console it said undefined

Comment: Please post your back-end code which accepts file-data.

Comment: @QuangBìnhĐinh It should log something. console.log("ResData: " + JSON.stringify(res.data)) try this in the then block mabye

Comment: I try to log the entire error and it show me ''Network Error" with the stack "createError@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:138333:26\nhandleError@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?...". The stack error is very long and I don't know why